Cannot click the "Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)" button when developing Flutter apps in Android studio
I am developing a Flutter app in Android studio, but I am having trouble clicking the "Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)" button. I've done a lot of research but haven't been able to solve the problem. Do you know the cause?
▼Environment
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
macOS Sonoma 14.0
M1 Max
enter image description here
I asked "Claude3", searched Google and Stack overflow, but could not find a solution.

Bro... To build Bundle or APK, you should open your android folder by Android Studio, not the whole Flutter project

Thank you so much!
The button has been successfully displayed.

LOL bro. Anyway, can you help me mark my answer below as Correct Answer? I would help me inscrease my reputation. Thank you.

Sorry, to late reply I tried to feedback and stack overflow said below sentence.

Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.


Well I remembered, there is a button looks like a Check Mark. Not the upvote button...

I clicked on the check mark and it turned green!

That is because you are opening your entire Flutter project by Android Studio. To show the build Bundle/APK button, you should open your android folder inside your Flutter project.
